# Run joint_state_publisher_gui with specific joint values

Tags: ros2, joint-state-publisher, ros-galactic

is there any possibility to launch the joint_state_publisher_gui with specific joint values?
For example, I want to set the joint value of `joint1` to a specific value.

I am looking for something like:

```sh
ros2 run joint_state_publisher_gui joint_state_publisher_gui joint_slew:=0.3
```

or load the joint position values with a yaml file.